# C stack with arrays

Tags: c, stack

I am trying to store arrays in a stack;

```
int *orderStack[2];
int orderSize=2;
int orderTop=0;

void pushOrder(int newOrder[2]) {


    if(orderTop>=orderSize) {
        int i;
        int *stack2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*orderSize*2);
        for(i=0; i<orderSize; i++) {
            stack2[i] = orderStack[i];
        }

        orderStack = stack2;
        orderSize *= 2;
    }


    orderStack[numberTop][0] = newOrder[0];
    orderStack[numberTop++][0] = newOrder[1];


    int temp, i, j, k;

    for (j = 0; j < numberTop; ++j) {
        for (k = j + 1; k < numberTop; ++k) {
            if (orderStack[j][1] > orderStack[k][1]) {
                temp = orderStack[j][1];
                orderStack[j][1] = orderStack[k][1];
                orderStack[k][1] = temp;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

But this it gives this error: [Error] assignment to expression with array type for the line

```
orderStack = stack2;
```

I read more then 20 questions about this error, arrays and stacks but I could not find what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> int *orderStack[2];

In this statement you are declaring orderStack as an array. The compiler allocates 2 slots in this array, each of which can store a pointer to integer. You can assign to these slots:

```
orderStack[0] = stack1;
orderStack[1] = stack2;
```

where stack1 and stack2 are of type `int *`

But you cannot assign orderStack itself - that wouldn't make any sense to the compiler.

If you want to be able to assign orderStack itself then you would declare it as:

```
int **orderStack;
```

However, now you will have to first assign it to an array of arrays, and then populate the elements of this array (which would be arrays of int)